# How to combine these two codes in knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

js and this is one of my first programs.I have two pieces of code in separate files and I don't know how to work these two pieces of code into one code.I know this looks pretty easy but me bieng a newbie , your help will be highly appreciated.

```
//Knockout file to add/ remove rows
       <html>
       <script src="C:\Users\neha.uniyal\Downloads\knockout-3.3.0.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
         function InsertRow(name) {
        var self = this;
        self.name = name; 
          }

        function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        // Editable data
        self.rows = ko.observableArray([
            new InsertRow(""),

        ]);
        self.addRow= function() {
            self.rows.push(new InsertRow(""));
        }
        self.removeRow= function(row) { self.rows.remove(row) }
            }

               ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
        </script>
       <body>
       <h2>Application</h2>

        <table>
        <thead><tr>
            <th>File name</th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:rows">
            <tr>
                <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
               <td>
                <select>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no" selected>No</option>
               </select></td>
                <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeRow">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
       </table>

       <button data-bind="click:addRow">Add Row</button>
       </body>
       </html>


//File to display upload-file control on selecting yes option:
 <html>
       <script src="C:\Users\neha.uniyal\Downloads\knockout-3.3.0.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
    var viewModel = {
    types: ["Yes", "No"],
    type: ko.observable("No"),
    isType: function(type) {
       return type === this.type();   
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        </script>
       <body>
      Choose : <select data-bind="options: types, value: type"></select>
<hr/>
<span data-bind="visible: isType('Yes')"><input type = "file"> </span>
<span data-bind="visible: isType('No')" ></span>

       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: you mean to say you want to merge 2 vm's into one vm ?

Comment: I can see a Choose dropdown in your second html file. Do you want this to be placed instead of select in first html file? can you please provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what you are looking for exactly.. But have prepared [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranparab0/fctve06r/).
have a look on it. hope that helps you.

```js
function InsertRow(name, hasFile) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.hasFile = ko.observable(hasFile);
    
    self.isType = function (hasFile) {
        return hasFile === this.hasFile();
    };
}

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Editable data
    self.rows = ko.observableArray([
    new InsertRow("", 'No')]);
    self.addRow = function () {
        self.rows.push(new InsertRow("", 'No'));
    }
    self.removeRow = function (row) {
        self.rows.remove(row)
    };

    self.types = ko.observableArray(["Yes", "No"]);
    self.type = ko.observable("No");
    //self.isType = function (type) {
    //    return type === this.type();
    //};

}


ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h2>Application</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>File name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:rows">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input data-bind="value: name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: $root.types, value: hasFile"></select>
                <br/> <span data-bind="visible: isType('Yes')">
                    <input type = "file"/> 
                </span>
 <span data-bind="visible: isType('No')"></span>

            </td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeRow">Remove</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click:addRow">Add Row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

well to merge two viewModels just try like this

**ViewModel:**

```
function InsertRow(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
}

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    // Editable data
    self.rows = ko.observableArray([
    new InsertRow(""),
    ]);
    self.addRow = function () {
        self.rows.push(new InsertRow(""));
    }
    self.removeRow = function (row) {
        self.rows.remove(row)
    }
}

var viewModel = {
    types: ["Yes", "No"],
    type: ko.observable("No"),
    isType: function (type) {
        return type === this.type();
    }
};

var vm ={  //merging here
    vm1:new AppViewModel(),
    vm2:viewModel
}
ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

**View :**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>File name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:vm1.rows"> /*always refer via view-model instance */
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input data-bind="value: name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="no" selected>No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.vm1.removeRow">Remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click:vm1.addRow">Add Row</button>//File to display upload-file control on selecting yes option: Choose :
<select data-bind="options: vm2.types, value: vm2.type"></select>
<hr/>
<span data-bind="visible: vm2.isType('Yes')"><input type = "file"/> </span>

<span data-bind="visible: vm2.isType('No')"></span>
```

working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/24550/)**

Just incase if you are trying to make everything under one viewmodel check this fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/24551/)**

Comment: I marked your reply as answer too.Presently I don't have sufficient scores to rate answers as I'm a beginner here

Comment: you can mark only one answer as best . not both . you can further upvote by clicking up arrow & tick . you have rights i guess